# Is there a way to integrate a running window in a gtk application

Tags: gtk

If there is a window already running on your system is there a way for a gtk window to capture it inside itself?

Comment: Certainly some programs do it, so it's possible...

Comment: @JiříBaum such as?

Comment: Hmm, the only one I can find quickly is `xswallow`; I've also seen this done in a presentation, where one of the slides contained the speaker's running program (maybe 15-20 years ago; as I recall, parts of the presentation were done in sodipodi). Either way, it was a long time ago

Comment: The principle is to tell the other program that you're now the window manager, but I never knew more details than that